# can't read field info from access database when using OleDbDataReader in C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb

i wrote a form based C# program to read/write to a access data base.
in it i have 2 tables: User and Item
the following code should have read a spesific field from the User table and return it to me based on the field number
but, i can't get it to work for some reason... help would be good at this point (4AM)

```
 public string UserGetField(int user_id,int field)
        {
            string found="";
            string command="";
            switch (field)
            {
                case 1://first_name
                    command+= "first_name";
                    break;
                case 2://last_name
                      command+= "last_name";
                    break;
                case 3://grade
                      command+= "grade";
                    break;
                case 4://phone
                      command+= "phone";
                    break;
                case 5://address
                      command+= "address";
                    break;
                case 6://item
                    command += "item";
                    break;
            }
            cmd.CommandText = "select '" + command + "' from User where user_id = '" + user_id + "'";
            con.Open(); // open the connection
            OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                found += dr["first_name"].ToString();
            }
            con.Close();
            return found;
        }
```

Comment: Is user id a string? It seems unlikely, so it should not be quoted: `... where user_id = " + user_id;`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    cmd.CommandText = "select [" + command + "] from User where user_id = '" + user_id + "'";
```

Also, you're dynamically choosing the select field but always looking for the first_name field in the result.  Change to

```
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            found += dr[0].ToString();  // first field value
        }
```

Comment: I personally prefer `String.Format` over clunky string concatentation: `cmd.CommandText = string.Format("select [{0}] from User where user_id = '{1}'", command, user_id);` though this would probably also be improved using SQL parameters.

Comment: freezes and shows error in OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); saying something is wrong in the "from"

Comment: Look at cmd.CommandText in the debugger and see if it is valid SQL

Comment: Also what should happen if field < 1 or field > 6?

Comment: @D Stanley i used first_name just because i thought it was the probelm, the right code is found += dr[command].ToString();    about lower the 1 and bigger then 6, right now i can't make it to work, later i'll think on how to limit it

Comment: Either Field <1 or >6 or one of the field names you're using is not in the User table, otherwise it would be valid SQL.

Comment: @DStanley the problem is still in this line cmd.CommandText = "select [" + command + "] from User where user_id = '" + user_id + "'"; it shows me that the error is in the "from"

Comment: Post the value of cmd.CommandText.  I'm betting it's not valid SQL.

Comment: @DStanley sorry for being a n00b, but how do i post the value?

Comment: with input field 1 its: select [first_name] from User where user_id = '1'

Comment: Try putting brackets around User - it is a reserved word in Access.

Comment: still error from OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); now oledbexception was unhandled

Answer (score 0):

Try this ?

```
    public string UserGetField(int user_id, int field)
    {
        var columns = new string[] { "first_name", "last_name", "grade", "phone", "address", "item" };

        var list = new List<string>();
        string command = columns[field - 1];
        var sql = string.Format("select '{0}' from User where user_id = '{1}'", command, user_id);
        var conStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\test.mdb"; //

        using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
            OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                list.Add(dr[command].ToString());
            }
        }
        return string.Join(",", list.ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: still problems with    OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

Answer (score 0):

this is the final version that works... swithced from table named User to Kids and made someother changes

```
 public string UserGetField(int user_id,int field)
        {
            string found="";
            string command="";
            switch (field)
            {
                case 1://first_name
                    command+= "first_name";
                    break;
                case 2://last_name
                      command+= "last_name";
                    break;
                case 3://grade
                      command+= "grade";
                    break;
                case 4://phone
                      command+= "phone";
                    break;
                case 5://address
                      command+= "address";
                    break;
                case 6://item
                    command += "item";
                    break;
            }
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT " + command + " FROM Kids WHERE user_id = " + user_id + "";
            con.Open(); // open the connection
            OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                found = dr[command].ToString();      
            }
            con.Close();
            return found;
        }
```